# Visual Studio Code .NET Core debugger not hitting a breakpoint

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a problem trying to debug applications written in .NET Core in Visual Studio Code. Here is the setup:
I'm using a virtual machine running Debian 9 (with the default GUI). I've installed .Net Core SDK 2.1, and Visual Studio Code 1.30.0. Installed the extensions for C# 1.17.1. I've created simple project:

```
class MyProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello You Angel!");
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "-c nautilus /home/", }; 
        Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
        proc.Start();
    }
}
```

If I run the program, in executes, and produces the correct output.
In the debug window I pressed the gear button to edit the  `launch.jason` file[image: Debug window]

Here it is what it looks like:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.1",
 "configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/HelloWorld.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld",
        // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "externalConsole": false,
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
 ,]
}
```

I've put a breakpoint in the project:
[image: Breakpoint]

and when I hit the green triangle button, the breakpoint it not hit. Actually I think that non of the code i executed at all.
Is there something I'm missing to get this app it debugging mode?

Please help!

Comment: assume you have tried a clean/re-build?

Comment: Yep, didn't make any difference :( Actually this Process start in the code is to assure myself, that no code has been executed at all (when I press the green triangle button)

Comment: i have to ask - but are you in debug mode in visual studio?

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm using Visual Studio Code, if there is such a setting in VS Code, I'm not finding it unfortunately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was having the same issue on a different setup. Running windows 10 using VSCode and dotnet sdk 2.2.

I found a few answers browsing through gissues [Here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1005).

And [This one I think fixed my problem](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs#net-cli-projects-projectjson)

I also noticed to make sure I was selecting the correct "c:/projectdir/bin/debug/projectname.dll" when asked to attach the debugger to a process.

After that VSCode successfully hit my breakpoint.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But I no longer work for the company that this question is related to, so I can't make the exact setup to verify that this is the solution or not. :) But anyways thanks for the effort!

Comment: Absolutely! This may not be a fix-all, but I figured it may help someone in a similar situation in the future if they come across this thread. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 6):

1) In terminal go to your project and write

```
dotnet restore
dotnet clean
dotnet build
```

2) Check paths of "program" and "cwd" in your configurations (launch.json).

Comment: The first two commands passed successfully but the third - 
`No executable found matching command "dotnet-rebuild"`

Comment: 2) How can I check them. If you mean if they are there - the answer is - yes they exist, I'm not sure what the {workspaceFolder} returns, but I've tried with the absolute path ... `/home/debianusr/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/.......` the same result

Comment: "Dotnet build"*

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone hits this problem when they have 'converted' a Class Library project to a Console Application here are the symptoms and cause that I found:

I had mistakenly created a Class Library when I actually wanted a Console Application. I've made this same mistake in .NET Framework projects before and so thought I'll just convert it, no problem. So I altered the Output Type and gave it a Startup Object. The project ran but breakpoints were not hit.

It took me a while to find out why; it was because I'd created the original Class Library project as a .NET Standard project. When I created a new project (same code) as .NET Core (rather than .NET standard) the breakpoints were hit.

Quite interesting that you can actually switch a .NET standard Class Library project to Console Application, as it appears you can't create that setup through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my project file from netcoreapp3.0 to netcoreapp2.2 and everything build fine but my breakpoints did not hit. After deleting the bin and obj directories, I got an error that the executable dll could not be found. Turned out I had to also change my launch.json file.

In .vscode/launch.json make sure to check your program folder and executable exists.